# Windows 7 not in boot menu on dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Lubuntu and created 3 partitions:

- 1 swap
- 1 Lubuntu
- 1 Windows

I turned my laptop on and I got the boot menu and I looked for Windows 7, but there's just Lubuntu.

The device is a Toshiba Satellite c855-s5203 with 2 GB RAM.

I have checked in the drive application and Windows does not show up.

How can I fix this?

Comment: try boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you flattened your WIN7 partition, although you didn't want to.

- boot into lubuntu
- install Gparted with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```

  - open it
  - look at the partitions (you may post here a screenshot too)

In both cases (partition still there / partition erased) you could try to rescue it, but in different ways. Just update the question.

Anyway, especially if the partition is still there, but it's not recognized, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair could be useful.

Comment: I was just to start it by my pc drive over heated and lost all the stuff on the drive

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sudo update-grub
```

in your lubuntu ,then reboot to see if Win7 appear in the menu.